# Android layout file grayed out

Tags: android, android-layout

I made an Android layout file recently, and it worked like normal with being able to edit it via the text and design tabs.

Then, I don't know what I did, but the text in the file got grayed out, the android ui icon went away where the files are listed on the left hand side, and I can't call them from inside my Java code. What can I do to convert these files back to Android layout files? Cleaning and rebuilding doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't put layout files into subfolders, that's why they're not working.

Move them out of the subfolder and into the main folder and they will work again.